# AppDomain probing problems

Tags: c#, .net, appdomain

I am trying to load a strongly named assembly that is located at a user-defined location into an AppDomain using this code:

```
    AppDomainSetup ads1 = new AppDomainSetup();
    if (ads1.PrivateBinPath != null)
    {
        ads1.PrivateBinPath += ads1.PrivateBinPath.Length == 0 ? "" : Path.PathSeparator.ToString();
    }
    ads1.PrivateBinPath += @"c:\work\abc1";
    sandbox1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandbox1", null, ads1);
    Object o1 = sandbox1.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(@"abc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f10808f3df0adc34", "Abc.Def");
```

When I run I get this error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Users\gel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplicat
ion1\ConsoleApplication1\bin\Debug\abc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f10808f3df0adc34' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the fil
e specified.
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stack
Mark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& st
ackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& st
ackMark, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence, Byte[] hashValue, AssemblyHashAlgorithm hashAlgorithm, Boole
an forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(String assemblyFile, Evidence securityEvidence)
   at System.Activator.CreateInstanceFromInternal(String assemblyFile, String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, C
ultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, Evidence securityInfo)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFrom(String assemblyFile, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at System.AppDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(String assemblyName, String typeName)
   at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\gel\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:li
ne 69
```

It is as though the AppDomain is not looking in the PrivateBinPath at all. What am I not doing right? I've double checked in an Explorer window and I can see the assembly at the location that I specified in the PrivateBinPath. It works fine if I just do Assembly.LoadFile and specify the right path, but that'd defeating the purpose of trying to load it in another AppDomain.

Comment: Be aware that when you run the following code your assembly will "bleed" into the current app domain: Object o1 = sandbox1.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(@"abc, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=f10808f3df0adc34", "Abc.Def");

Comment: Maybe  useful using AppDomain ***`https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6d89e2ce-3528-465f-9740-7e22aa7b7aae/slow-performance-with-dynamic-grouping-and-reportviewer-in-local-mode?forum=sqlreportingservices`***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your code and this works just great. See the changes you needs to be done.

```
        AppDomainSetup ads1 = new AppDomainSetup();
        if (ads1.PrivateBinPath != null)
        {
            ads1.PrivateBinPath += ads1.PrivateBinPath.Length == 0 ? "" : Path.PathSeparator.ToString();
        }
        ads1.PrivateBinPath += @"D:\ConsoleApplication1\ClassLibrary1\bin\debug";
        AppDomain sandbox1 = AppDomain.CreateDomain("sandbox1", null, ads1);
        Object o1 = sandbox1.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(@"ClassLibrary1.dll", "ClassLibrary1.Class1");
```

Comment: Give it a try it'll load your assembly from any location. e.g. c:\temp\ or whatever.

Comment: ugh I can't believe it, you are right. The AssemblyName parameter is not an "assembly name"? I would never have figured it out without your help. I can't believe how inconsistent the naming is - AppDomain has a CreateInstanceFrom method that takes a AssemblyFile parameter, which IS the file. AppDomain and Assembly have an AssemblyString parameter in other methods, and elsewhere they call what I was using the "Assembly Name"

Comment: Yeah, that naming is really confusing. May be that's why they placed an extra comment on the "assembly name" parameter in the method CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap()

Answer (score 1):

I belive it fails to load that assembly into your current AppDomain, not to the new one (where it likley loaded ok).

The behavior sometimes called "leaking types to aother domain" and casued by attempt to use the created object directly. To work around it one need to create class completely in the other AppDomain (i.e. by running some custom code that deal with creation) and than exposing only interface/classes known to both domain. Check out [Unloadable plugins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/73096/Unloadable-plugins) for details.

Short portion of code adopted from the article - create RemoteLoader class in other AppDomain with `CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap` and use that object to load/manage other types in the new AppDomain.

```
public class RemoteLoader : MarshalByRefObject
{ 
    public void Load(string assemblyName, string typeName)
    {
        object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(assemblyName, typeName);
        //Do something with instance, or return shared interface of it.
    }
}
```

Side note: unless you doing it for education purposes consider using existing plugin frameworks like [MEF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx).

Comment: I don't understand. How can it be loaded if it isn't finding the DLL? From the error I cannot conclude it is even looking in the right place. I tried to test your theory and I added this line: AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AppendPrivatePath(@"c:\work\abc1"); but it still doesn't work, same results.

Comment: the problem is you're not passing the arguments correct. Try my code that I just placed below this answer. @Alexei nice explanation.